# CSV to JSON without needing it to save in another json file using Python

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am looking for a way to convert the CSV data into JSON data without needing it to save it another JSON file. Is it possible?

So the following functionality needs to be carried out.

Sample Code:

```
 df= pd.read_csv("file_xyz.csv").to_json("another_file.json")
 data_json = pd.read_json("another_file.json")
```

Now, if I had to do the same thing **without** having to save my data in "another_file.json". **I want the data_json to have JSON data by directly performing some operations on CSV data**. Is it possible? How can we do that?

Comment: Just a `.to_json()` will return a JSON string, mate. Make sure you read the docs before posting a question.

Comment: @jezrael .   pd.read_csv("file_xyz.csv").to_dict() . This helps. Needed this for futhur processing.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.to_json`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html) without filename:

```
j = pd.read_csv("file_xyz.csv").to_json()
```

Or if want convert output to dictionary for next processing use [`DataFrame.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html):

```
d = pd.read_csv("file_xyz.csv").to_dict()
```

Comment: to_dict() This is what I was looking for. This helps!!! Thanks a lot :)